# Compare two lists of object linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have one online database on wcf and one offline database. I want to synchronize those so I started with mapping the online data into an object of offline data.

```
List<com.somee.wobservice.Customer> onlineCus = myservice.QueryCustomer();
List<Customer> offlineCus = dbc.Customers.ToList();
List<Customer> onlineCusMap = new List<Customer>();

foreach (com.somee.wobservice.Customer c in onlineCus)
{
     Customer cus = new Customer();
     cus.customer_id = c.customer_id;
     cus.customer_name = c.customer_name;
     cus.customer_email = c.customer_email;
     cus.password = c.password;
     cus.balance = c.balance;

     onlineCusMap.Add(cus);
 }
```

Now, I have 2 objects of the class Customer (a table in my database). But when I compared to get the except from them, it returned all data of the offline database (suppose to be no data because the data in those objects are same)

```
List<Customer> toInsert = offlineCus.Except(onlineCusMap).ToList();
```

Any suggestion to compare those 2 objects?

Comment: Does your `Customer` class override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? If not, that's why it's not finding any duplicates.

Comment: Try implementing IEquatable<customer> suggested by the msdn docs. Which overrides the above methods. Not sure if this is required though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon pointed out in the comment in order to use `Except` you would need to override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` in order to determine what distinguishes a customer; By default your comparator will be by reference which in most cases will not suffice.

An alternative to that would be to just query for any customers which do not exist in the `onlineCusMap` list. I think it's probably safe to assume that `customer_id` is going to be unique enough to distinguish a customer

```
List<Customer> toInsert = 
    offlineCus.Where(x => !onlineCusMap.Any(y => y.customer_id == x.customer_id))
              .ToList();
```

If you do decide to override `Equals` I suggest you read the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on how to do so correctly because it's not quite as simple as it may seem.

Comment: You're right, your linq statement looks more lovely than Equals example. Thanks a lot!!